# For honor gifted achievements

Tags: for-honor

Okay so I completed the knight and Viking story on normal, but I had yet to do the samurai section. I was playing online and I was gifted the complete story at normal trophy?! After this I completed the samurai story. Again, playing online and I was gifted the complete story at hard!!! What is happening here?

Comment: Did you play the Knight/Viking on normal and the Samurai on Hard?

Comment: No I play the knight on normal, the Viking on easy. Then got the complete game on normal trophy. I proceeded to complete the samurai on normal. Playing online and got gifted the trophy for completing the game on hard, this was well after completing the game on normal btw.

Comment: Not sure why you got Hard then. Normally when you complete the campaign on normal, you get the trophy for normal and the levels below it.

Comment: I've seen a few people on Reddit have had the same issue, they were playing brawl, which I always play on, rarely other game modes, and they got awarded the campaign trophies?!